# Whitespace error in the "Unique posts" count in /tools/post-feedback

Tags: bug, design, 10k-tools

On the [Post Feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback) 10K-tools page, there's way too much whitespace in the "Unique posts" count:

[image]

It's the same under all the other tabs.  Can we eliminate (most of) the whitespace or make it look more like:

[image]

The [suggested edts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits?filter=all&tab=All) stats?